# How to return the income message from https request using only the native https module?

Tags: node.js, https

i'm trying to do a HTTPS request in nodejs as follows:

```
var makeRequest = options => {
    const req = https.request(options, res => {
        // console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
        // console.log('headers:', res.headers);
        res.on('data', d => {
            process.stdout.write(d);
        });
    });
    req.on('error', e => {
        console.error(e);
    });
    req.end();
    //   return results;
};
```

Instead of print it i would like to return this value to another function, that should looks like:
{items:[..,..,...]}

Comment: i know about request and axios, but i was trying to figure out a way with less dependencies  to do that

Answer (score 0):

one way would be writing the function with the callback, where the function send the request ,as the response we will getting would be stream we would have store in the temporary variable, and after successfully getting the whole response, will have to pass the response to the callback function.

```
const https = require('https');
const StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;

const options = {
    hostname: 'encrypted.google.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET'
  };


function getData(callbackfun){
    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        const decoder = new StringDecoder('utf-8');
        let responseData = '';
        res.on('data', (data) => {
            responseData += decoder.write(data);      
        });
        res.on('end',function(){
            responseData += decoder.end();
            callbackfun(responseData)
        })
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
        callbackfun(e)
    });
    req.end()   
}


getData((result)=>{
    console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: Great that helped me a lot, tks ravi!